# CSS container height zero... why not height of contents?

Tags: css, height, margin

I am not seeing any vertical space (specified by the 50px margin in lineitem) between lineitem elements. However, if I add something like height:40px; to lineitem's css format, then both the height and the margin are respected. Why doesn't lineitem just derive the heights of the input and label elements and add the margin to whatever that is?

```
<div id="checkoutform">
<div class="lineitem">
<input type="text" name="EMAIL">
<label for="EMAIL">Your E-Mail:</label>
</div>

<div class="lineitem">
<input type="text" name="NAME">
<label for="NAME">Your Name:</label>
</div>
</div><!-- #checkoutform -->
```

And the CSS:

```
#checkoutform .lineitem {
    margin:0px 15px 50px 0px;
    clear:both;
}

#checkoutform label {
    float: right;
    text-align:right;
    font-family:"Open Sans";
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:14px;
}

#checkoutform input {
    width:280px;
    float:right;
    font-family:"Open Sans";
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could have to do with the `line-height` of your element's content (if you've set that elsewhere). All elements in the DOM and "essentially" rendered as text. If you don't have a height set for the element, it assumes the line-height for the calculated height, not necessarily the height of the content. You could essentially "force" the `.lineitem` height be adding a clearfix element, or adding a `clear:both;`to one of it's children elements.

I suggest looking in this direction as it seems that floating the element as a means to do layout is not the accepted practice.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple:

You need to clear the `float`s inside `.lineitem`.

Add this to your `css`, this clears the floats with a `pseudo` element without any need to modify your `HTML`.

```
#checkoutform .lineitem:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/jrkph1ra/

**The reason this works:**

Floated elements get out of the normal flow of height calculation of their containers.

An element that follows the floated elements with `clear:both;` will mean that no floating elements are allowed on the left or the right side of that element, it moves the margin edge of the element below the margin edge of all relevant floats, forcing the browser to take into account the height of the floated elements into the height calculation.

This element can be a pseudo element of the parent of the floated elements so no HTML modification is needed.

"Clearing the floats" is a common practice and well-tested.

If you use it frequently you can create a class like `clearfix` and add that class to all relevant elements.

```
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}
```

Then add `.clearfix` to all relevant elements with floated children.

**Demo** https://jsfiddle.net/jrkph1ra/1/

**`display: table;` vs `display:block;`**

Both `display: table;` and `display:block;` will generate block level elements, the major difference is that `table` will only expand to the width of its content, in this case a width of `0` but `block` will extend to the width of its container, so using `table` minimizes the footprint of this method.

Comment: This works, but I am not really sure why. I had not heard of the display: table; option before. I wonder if this is a good fix, or some sort of band-aid? I am using this code to essentially have a few rows of user-input with things being right-justified.

Comment: @Trygve I added some explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for this. What is the difference between display:table and display:block... and why should I use "table" in this case?

Comment: @Trygve added more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Add "float: left" to .line-item

https://jsfiddle.net/q6ytv3tt/1/

```css
#checkoutform .lineitem {
    margin:0px 15px 50px 0px;
    clear:both;
    float:left;


}
```